# Difference between returning +{} or {} in perl from a function, and return ref or value

Tags: perl

I just started work with a new team new place. They told me we return ref instead of value in our perl modules. Also I saw something like `return +{foo=>'bar'}; and return {foo=>'bar'};` Whats the difference? And whether to return ref or value?

Comment: It is used occasionally to disambiguate between a HASH reference and a BLOCK expression. You can read more about it under [`perldoc perlref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html)

Comment: Oh dear. Perl standards written by non-Perl programmers! Surely you don't have to write `return \1`? But always returning hash or array references is a recipe for memory leaks.

Comment: "return ref instead of value"... I've seen that. It typically means that the return value will *always* be a reference (whether hash, array etc), even if it is empty. So if all is good, you may get a populated hash reference, but on failure or success but nothing accomplished, an empty ref `{}` (hash ref in this case). Then, the caller might: `if (! exists $return->{expected}){do_something(); ...}`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `+` in `return +{foo=>'bar'}` is completely useless.

---

First, some background.

The Perl language has ambiguities. Take for example

```
sub f {
   {  }     # Is this a hash constructor or a block?
}
```

`{ }` is valid syntax for a block ("bare loop").
`{ }` is valid syntax for a hash constructor.
And both are allowed as a statement!

So Perl has to guess. Perl usually guesses correctly, but not always. You can give it "hints". Unary-`+` can be used to do this. Unary-`+` is a completely transparent operator; it does nothing at all. However, it must be followed by an expression (not a statement). `{ }` has only one possible meaning as an expression.

```
+{ }   # Must be a hash constructor.
```

Similarly, you can trick Perl to guess the other way.

```
{; }   # Perl looks ahead, and sees that this must be a block.
```

Here's an example where Perl guesses wrong:

```
map { {} } 1..5   # ok. Creates 5 hashes and returns references to them.
map {}, 1..5      # XXX Perl guesses you were using "map BLOCK LIST".
map +{}, 1..5     # ok. Perl parses this as "map EXPR, LIST".
```

---

As for the code in the question, `return` must be followed by an expression (if anything), so there's only one possible interpretation for `return { ... };`, so the `+` is completely useless there.

Most people only disambiguate when necessary. Others might add `+` whenever it's ambiguous (even if Perl would guess right). But this is the first time I've heard of using `+` in front of every hash constructor.

Comment: Very nice explanation that removes the ambiguity from the ambiguity.

Comment: Note that since `map {}, 1..5;` has only one valid interpretation, so Perl could figure it out what you meant instead of guessing. 1) That assumes no one makes any syntax errors, and 2) When you disambiguate, you're not only disambiguating for Perl, but for the reader as well. In short, it's best to know the meaning of tokens as soon as possible.

Comment: Unary-`+` doesn't even impose scalar context! `perl -e'@a = 4..6; CORE::say for +@a'`

Answer (score 11):

> Whats the difference?

Those are exactly the same, so the `+` is extraneous. You can see this by using [B::Deparse](http://perldoc.perl.org/B/Deparse.html):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'sub foo { return { foo => "bar" } }'
sub foo {
    return {'foo', 'bar'};
}
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e'sub foo { return +{ foo => "bar" } }'
sub foo {
    return {'foo', 'bar'};
}
-e syntax OK
```

In both cases, you're returning a reference to a hash.

---

As Hunter McMillen said in a comment, there are some cases where you need to use the unary `+` operator to resolve ambiguity.

For example, to distinguish between an anonymous hash and a block in a `map`:

```
$ perl -e'@a = map { $_ => "foo" }, 1..3'   # { ... } treated as a block
syntax error at -e line 1, near "},"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

$ perl -e'@a = map +{ $_ => "foo" }, 1..3'  # { ... } treated as a hashref
```

---

> And whether to return ref or value?

By "returning a value," I assume your coworkers mean something like this:

```
sub foo {
    my %bar = ( baz => 'qux' );
    return %bar;  # as opposed to \%bar
}

my %hash = foo();
```

Subroutines can only return a list of scalars, so this is roughly equivalent to

```
my %hash = ('baz', 'qux');
```

If `%bar` contains many items, copying this list becomes expensive, so it can be better to return a reference instead:

```
sub foo {
    my %bar = ( baz => 'qux' );
    return \%bar;
}

my $hashref = foo();
```

Comment: Note: Deparse is a good reference, but it's not definitive. If you wanted a definitive comparison, you could use `diff -u <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec,foo -e'sub foo { return { foo => "bar" } }' 2>&1 ) <( perl -MO=Concise,-exec,foo -e'sub foo { return +{ foo => "bar" } }' 2>&1 )`.