# Why no interpolation within `map` BLOCK?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

This throws an error in Perl v5.20:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @a = (2,3,9);
my %b = map { "number $_" => 2*$_ } @a;
```

Error:

```
syntax error at a.pl line 4, near "} @a"
Execution of a.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

This doesn't:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @a = (2,3,9);
my %b = map { "number ".$_ => 2*$_ } @a;
```

Why is interpolation of `$_` disallowed within the `map` BLOCK?

Comment: It's not the interpolation. If you remove the `$_` from the string it still throws the error.

Comment: Putting parentheses inside the BLOCK will help.

Comment: @HåkonHægland so I could just write `{; "number $_" => 2*$_ }` instead, right?

Comment: @jlovegren Yes correct :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`map` has two syntax:

```
map BLOCK LIST
map EXPR, LIST
```

Perl must determine which syntax you are using. The problem is that both `BLOCK` and `EXPR` can start with `{` because `{ ... }` can be the hash constructor (e.g. `my $h = { a => 1, b => 2 };`).

That means that Perl's grammar is ambiguous. When an ambiguity is encountered, `perl` guesses what you mean after looking ahead a little. In your situation, it guessed wrong. It guessed `{` was the start of a hash constructor instead of the start of a block. You will need to disambiguate explicitly.

The following are convenient ways to disambiguate blocks and hash constructors:

```
+{ ... }   # Not a valid block, so must be a hash constructor.
{; ... }   # Perl looks head, and sees that this must be a block.
```

So in your case, you could use

```
my %b = map {; "number $_" => 2*$_ } @a;
```

---

Related: [Difference between returning +{} or {} in perl from a function, and return ref or value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42100478/589924)

Comment: @Сухой27, The error message is more precise with `+{ ... }`, but it's the same error: a comma is expected after the end of the expression.