# Perl hashes don't work as expected

Tags: hashmap, perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sub f { {
  a => 1,
  b => 2
} }

sub g { {
  %{f()},
  c => 3,
  d => 4,
} }

use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper g();
```

The above code outputs

```
$VAR1 = 'a';
$VAR2 = 1;
$VAR3 = 'b';
$VAR4 = 2;
$VAR5 = 'c';
$VAR6 = 3;
$VAR7 = 'd';
$VAR8 = 4;
```

despite in my understanding it should output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 1,
          'c' => 3,
          'b' => 2,
          'd' => 4
        };
```

What is my misunderstanding?

Comment: I was going to write an answer to the effect that it's a context problem. But for all it's a bit icky style, `f()` does return a hashref, but `g()` returns a list. I think it must be to do with the unpacking `%{f()]` causing a return in a list context.

Comment: @hoffmeister: You haven't explained why `Data::Dumper` works with one function but not the other. This is clear, because `%{ f() }` works fine,

Comment: Quasi-duplicate of [Difference between returning +{} or {} in perl from a function, and return ref or value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42100478/589924)

Comment: @ikegami , you're right, i did not realise that perl sees it as a code block, not a reference. However, i do not think you're answer makes it clear from a sub-routine you can either return a single variable or a list. So here when we call g() Data::Dumper it prints a list. I've only known data::dumper to print a hash if you pass a reference, hence why we need to make it a hash reference somehow. let me know if you want me to delete my initial comment

Comment: @hoffmeister, I don't see the point of explaining that subs can return multiple scalars (and neither did Borodin, for that matter). The problem is that `{ }` isn't doing what it's expected to be doing. I explained why that's the case, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that a pair of braces is ambiguous in Perl, and may be either a block or an anonymous hash

Because of the contents of the hash in your `g` (please use better names) perl has assumed that you are writing a code block, which is just a list of scalar values

Make it more explicit like this and your code will function as you expect

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

sub foo {
    {
        a => 1,
        b => 2,
    }
}

sub bar {
    my $href = {
        %{ foo() },
        c => 3,
        d => 4,
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd bar();
```

#### output

```
{ a => 1, b => 2, c => 3, d => 4 }
```

Comment: Are `foo/bar` really better function names than `f/g` ? I mean, none are a good name for a real code, but for a minimal example, `f` and `g` seem fine to me..

Comment: @Dada: There is a reason why the community settled on `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` instead of `f`, `g`, and `h`. Shorter names will always be preferred without another overriding reason (which is why the more common Perl language words are also generally the shorter ones). The problem is that single-letter identifiers tend to "disappear" into the the surrounding symbols, so `%{foo()}` is much clearer than `%{f()}`.

Answer (score 7):

The Perl language has ambiguities. Take for example

```
sub some_sub {
   {  }     # Is this a hash constructor or a block?
}
```

`{ }` is valid syntax for a block ("bare loop").
`{ }` is valid syntax for a hash constructor.
And both are allowed as a statement!

So Perl has to guess. Perl usually guesses correctly, but not always. In your case, it guessed correctly for `f()`, but not for `g()`.

To fix this, you can give Perl "hints". Unary-`+` can be used to do this. Unary-`+` is a completely transparent operator; it does nothing at all. However, it must be followed by an expression (not a statement). `{ }` has only one possible meaning as an expression.

```
+{ }   # Must be a hash constructor.
```

Similarly, you can trick Perl to guess the other way.

```
{; }   # Perl looks ahead, and sees that this must be a block.
```

So in this case, you could use

```
sub g { +{
  %{f()},
  c => 3,
  d => 4,
} }
```

or

```
sub g { return {
  %{f()},
  c => 3,
  d => 4,
} }
```

(`return` must also be followed by an expression if anything.)