# Is there a way to get Perl to support wildcard command-line arguments like "*.txt" on Windows?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line-arguments, wildcard

When passing wildcard arguments to a Perl script on *nix systems, like

```
$ perl script.pl *.txt
```

shells like Bash will expand all wildcard (`*`, `?`, `[]`) matches, consequently populating `@ARGV` with all matches.

Windows CMD, however, doesn't perform such an expansion before running the Perl interpreter.

Is it possible to get Perl to handle this expansion internally to mimic *nix shells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core module [File::DosGlob](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::DosGlob) provides the tools to expand wildcards in the manner a Windows user would expect, so it's just a question to use the `glob` provided by this module as follows:

```
use File::DosGlob qw( glob );

@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV;
```

---

Note that doing this using the builtin `glob` would break paths that contain spaces, a relatively common occurrence on Windows. It would also mishandle `*.*`, which is expected to return all files.

Note that it's best to expand the patterns after processing command-line options to avoid risking expanding the pattern into a command-line option.

```
use File::DosGlob qw( glob );
use Getopt::Long  qw( GetOptions );

GetOptions(...)
   or die_usage();

@ARGV = map glob, @ARGV;
```

---

For a one-liner, you could use the following:

```
perl -MFile::DosGlob=glob -ne"BEGIN { @ARGV = map glob, @ARGV } ..." ...
```

The `BEGIN` ensures the code is run before the input-reading loop created by `-n` starts.

Answer (score 2):

[`glob`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) supports wildcard expansion, so use one can use it to alter `@ARGV` on the fly:

```
BEGIN { @ARGV = map +glob, @ARGV; }
```

Running inside the [`BEGIN`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN%2C-UNITCHECK%2C-CHECK%2C-INIT-and-END) block ensures that `@ARGV` is modified before the rest of the code is even parsed, let alone run:

> A `BEGIN` code block is executed as soon as possible, that is, the moment it is completely defined, even before the rest of the containing file (or string) is parsed.

Comment: What is the plus operator for in `map +glob`?

Comment: @Grant McLean, Unary-`+` is a a no-op. It's sometimes used to disambiguate in situations where the grammar is ambiguous (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42100478/589924)), but this is not the case here. It has absolutely no effect here, and it can safely be omitted (as seen in my answer).