# MOSS Error-Unable to upload all files in a directory to MOSS Server

Tags: c++, windows-10, plagiarism-detection

I am trying to run a plagiarism check on all C++ files that are stored in an directory using MOSS.

`perl moss.pl -l cc -b pre.cpp *.cpp`

The above code is what I've used in the command line on windows 10. All C++ files are present in the working directory.

However I am getting the error

`File *.cpp does not exist. Request not sent.`

What am I doing wrong?

If i enter the file names manually it works fine. For example

`perl moss.pl -l cc -b pre.cpp a.cpp b.cpp c.cpp`

And I am able to check for plagiarism in these codes

But I have more than 200 C++ files to check for plagiarism. Is there any other way to do this other than entering the 200 file names manually?

Comment: I don't think SO is the right place to ask this. This site is for programming help, not software help.

Comment: In Windows, file name globbing is the responsibility of the program. Your `moss.pl` will have to take the `*.cpp` argument and pass it to `glob`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to get Perl to support wildcard command-line arguments like "\*.txt" on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58959611/is-there-a-way-to-get-perl-to-support-wildcard-command-line-arguments-like-tx)